# Creating a Macro or Formula to copy data through a query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Here is my formula that I'm looking to build off of:

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Table2,10,FALSE),"")

I don't know if I can use just a formula or if it has to be a macro. I am trying to create a query of one column in a list. The query will be for an ID in column A. This query will be done against another worksheet in the same workbook. (**Table1** and **Table2**)

If the ID of the first worksheet matches the ID in the other worksheet, it will copy data from **column J** of **Table1** to **column J** of **Table2**.
There are only two columns that will be used in this formula. **Column A** contains IDs for the initial lookup while **Column J** contains the data that needs to be copied

My formula already works but I need it to actually copy the values over to **column J** instead of just referencing. If I need to explain better/more, I'd be more than happy to do that.

Comment: Are you putting your formula in column `J`?  Because you should, from what I can gather.

Comment: do you want to copy the values, and have that overwrite the formula you use to retrieve the data?

Answer (score -1):

Would this do what you need?

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Table2,10,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A1,Table2,10,FALSE))
```

Comment: [Welcome to SuperUser](http://superuser.com/about) I didn't downvote, but you might have received a downvote because it's difficult to tell what **exactly** the asker wants to do because there is no response to the comments. Also, note the date on the question.